# Weird number of rows when joining two tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have this weird result when I perform a join on spark dataframes using Pyspark.
I have a dataframe `df1` where 
`print(df1.count())` gives

> 116066151

`print(df2.count())` gives

> 9418101

I perform a join like so:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=['SEQ_ID'], how='inner')
```

where `SEQ_ID` is common in both the dataframes.
But when i perform the count
`print(df3.count())` the number of rows it gives is

> 2950342258

Thats almsot 3 billion rows!!
I'm no SQL expert but I was under the assumption that when you do a join, the number of rows in the joined table will either be equal to or lesser than the number of rows in the largest of the joining tables. I read up on the join clause for pyspark and did not come across any mention of this. 
Am I missing something?
ANy insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank You

Comment: The cardinality of a join between A and B <= the cardinality of A * the cardinality of B. How many distinct seqid do you have in df1, df2?

Comment: Despite its name SEQ_ID seems to be non-unique in at least one of the tables.

Comment: Ah yes. The SEQ_ID is not exactly unique. In the sense that the other columns have different values for the same SEQ_ID. This explains the ballooning of the dataset. 
Thank You Lennart and Adam.